# Load word document content to PrintDocument

Tags: windows, winforms

I have a .doc or .dot file and I'd like to view it in PrintPreviewDialog. I heard that I only can view it if I can load the .doc content into PrintDocument object or atleast paint the content on.

Anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Word is required to load the .doc and generate the preview image of document.  Embedding Word in your own window used to be possible but support for this is rapidly disappearing.  The old DsoFramer control used to be the standard solution but you can no longer download it.  It got removed when the Office 2010 beta became available, an ominous sign.  Embedding it in a WebBrowser might still be possible, not sure.

The long term solution is to use Word itself to generate the preview.  Use the [Document.PrintPreview() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1x2ca5h%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: I work around this by invoke Word's PrintPreview. That makes the application depends on Word but not found any other way.